# Сравнения значений масивов

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

У нас есть несколько `div` с класом `iteam`, дальше нам нужно взять ключ у всех елементов `iteam` , после из базы берем значения `id`, после нам нужно сравнить `id` и `key` если они совпадают то отображать уже информацию в блоке! Всё работает к моменту сравнения, возможно из-за разных типов данных! Помогите решить проблему

```js
var Base = [{
    id: '0',
    h2: 'Text1',
    p: 'Text2'
  },
  {
    id: '1',
    h2: 'Text1',
    p: 'Text2'
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    h2: 'Text1',
    p: 'Text2'
  }
];

//Функция добавляет Key ЕЛЕМЕНТУ
function AppInitial() {
  $('.iteam').each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr('key', index);
  });
}
AppInitial();
//
function AutoBlock() {
  //Получаем значения key
  var key = $('.iteam').map(function(index) {
    var key = $(this).attr('key');
    return key;
  });
  //Получаем id из базы
  var id = Base.map(function(element) {
    var id = element.id;
    return id;
  });
  //
  Base.forEach(function(element) {
    if (id == key) {
      $(".iteam h2").text(element.h2);
      $(".iteam p").text(element.p);
    }
  });
}

AutoBlock();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='iteam'>
  <h2></h2>
  <p></p>
</div>
<div class='iteam'>
  <h2></h2>
  <p></p>
</div>
<div class='iteam'>
  <h2></h2>
  <p></p>
</div>
<div class='iteam'>
  <h2></h2>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: как Вы думаете, что возвращает функция `Array.map`? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp

Comment: приведите валидный пример

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function AutoBlock() {
  Base.forEach(function(element) {
    $(".iteam[key='" + element.id + "'] h2").text(element.h2);
    $(".iteam[key='" + element.id + "'] p").text(element.p);
  });
}
```

Comment: как правильно называеться ето выражения (".iteam[key='" + element.id + "'] p"), где можно посмотреть докум.

Comment: @DarkAdmiral "Attribute Equals" selector - https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: Никак не могу понять как оно сравнивает key и id

Comment: @DarkAdmiral оно не сравнивает, а ищет DOM элементы с классом `iteam`, у которых атрибут `key` равен `element.id`

Comment: Спасибо понял!!